# Redirect to specific php file when 404 is fired

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, rest

In my rest API I want shown a json error like this:

```
{"error": "url not correct"}
```

when the user insert a wrong request like this `localhost.com/api/` instead of this: `localhost/api`

I setup my `htaccess` as:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /v1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/api/error.php
```

The problem is that the redirect doesn't working and when a user insert a wrong request, as shown above, is displayed this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /api/meach was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost.it Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

now another "problem" I guess, could be the `http://localhost/api/error.php`, 'cause if I put the api on different server maybe I'll get also a not found? 
I'm not an expert in the `htaccess` configuration. Someone could help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would you rely on a message in this case rather than simply the 404 status code which gets returned?

Comment: @kingkero uhm well I return even a custom message when an error is throw. I shunk all the request in the index.php before of call other php file of the api

Comment: The problem is that, RewriteRule runs before the errorDocument directive, So a not existent request is being handled by the RewriteRule instead of the ErrorDocument directive.

Comment: @starkeen I update the htaccess and also I got the same response, the `htaccess` not redirect also. What I did wrong now? Notice that I put the `htaccess` in the project directory not in the htdocs folder

Comment: What did you type in the address bar to test this?

Comment: @BenjaminLücking I type this: `http://localhost.com/api/user` of course the correct link is: `http://localhost/api/user`.

Comment: You can't intercept with htaccess if the host is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **impossible** unless you are the owner of localhost.com .

Imagine somebody is typing `http://stackoverflow.com/api/user` in the address bar and you want to redirect him to `http://localhost/api/user`. That would be the same impossible challenge.

You can only "correct typos" *behind* `http://localhost/`:

Imagine anyone is trying to access `http://localhost/something/not/existing/`
then you can redirect him to `http://localhost/api/user/`

I hope my explanation is clear to understand.

Comment: I could redirect from stackoverflow to localhost if I own stackoverflow. =)